# AI2HTML - exporting images file inside created folder

Tags: javascript, java, adobe-illustrator

I am struggling to understand how to export the generated images from this script to the folder where the html has been exported.

I have slightly edited the original script to get the output folder as the name of the .ai file, the html file is working fine and is placed inside this folder, but the images are exported outside this folder.

This is the edited script: https://js.do/code/403281

Thank you so much,